# where or how does pyOpenCL looks for the clplatforms?

Tags: python, pyopencl

I am trying to use pyOpenCL in an IPython notebook, Ubuntu 16.4, Nvidia card. But, I am getting the error:

clGetPlatformIDs failed: unknown error -1001

However, if I run in terminal "clinfo" I get the 3 platforms installed. Where does PyOpenCL try to find the platforms? I can create a link in the folder that consults.

Comment: No idea about IPython, but can you run `pyopencl.get_platforms()` in a normal Python file?  That would help determine if this issue is an IPython one - or an issue with your system/installation.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more, here is the answer. In the case your computer has a platform or multiple, there should be located in Ubuntu here:

/etc/OpenCL/vendors

Then, you only have to copy/paste the icd files, in my case in the following path where I installed pyOpenCl.

/home/[username]/anaconda2/etc/OpenCL/vendors

And finally RESTART, otherwise it won't work(at least in my case)